# Make controls be inside of my slideshow and stuck always at same position

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I´ve been getting problems with the controls of my slideshow, i cant make the slideshow controls/navigation stuck at the bottom of the slideshow but inside the slideshow, the controls should always be at same position no matter the window size.

How you will see at the moment the controls outside the images and they will change position if i resize the window.

Site live: http://optential.co.nf/

```js
var seconds = 2; //time beetwen auto slide
var delay = 8; //time to restart auto slide

var slider = $('#slider');
var images = $('#slider .images');
var controls = $('<div>').addClass('controls');
slider.after(controls);
var width = images.width();
var slideClick = function () {  
  var b = $(this);
  $('.controls div').removeClass('current');
  b.addClass('current');
  var index = b.index();
  images.css('left', -1 * index * width);
};
$('#slider .images img').each(function (i) {
  var img = $(this);
  img.css('left', i * width);
  var button = $('<div>');
  controls.append(button);
  if (i == 0) { button.addClass('current') }
  button.click(function(){
    clearInterval(autoSlideInterval);
    slideClick.apply(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
       setInterval(autoSlide, seconds * 1000);     
    }, delay * 1000);
  });
});
var autoSlide = function(){
  var next = $('.controls .current').next();
  if (next.length) {
    slideClick.apply(next); 
  } else {
    var first = $('.controls div').first();
    slideClick.apply(first); 
  }
};
var autoSlideInterval = setInterval(autoSlide, seconds * 1000);
```

```css
html,
body { height: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("img/fundo1.jpg");
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .logo {
  width: 230px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 8px 8px 6%;
}

.header .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px; right: 25px;
}

.header .menu a {
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

.header .menu a:hover,
.header .menu a.current {
  color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
}

.header .move {
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header .move .center {
  margin: 260px auto 0;
  width: 360px;
}

.header .move h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 38px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.header .move p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.header .mail1 {
  background-image: url("img/email.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 560px; height: 560px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.header .mail1 form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  bottom: 220px; right: 155px;
}

.header .mail1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);

}
.header .mail1 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
 }

.header .mail1 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.header .mail1 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.header .mail1 a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header .mail1 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("img/barra.png");
  background-position: 12% 0%;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
}

#btn {
    width: 10em; 
  }

.mail2.fixed {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  position: fixed;
  display:block;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mail2 form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 600px;
}

.mail2 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mail2 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.mail2 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.mail2 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.mail2 a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 4%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mail2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 .top {
  padding: 8px 6px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.mail2 .top:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .images { 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1s;
  left: 0;
}

#slider .images img {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.controls {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.controls div {

  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.controls .current {
  background: red;
}

.mobile {
  min-width: 1300px;
}

.mobile .bar {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  color: #595B61;
  min-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile .bar img {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mobile .content {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 55% 50%, #F9F9F9 40%,#B6B5BD 120%);
  position: relative;
}

.mobile .content .mobimg {
  padding: 3em;
  margin-left:10%;
}

.mobile .content .mob {  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
  left: 60%;
}

.mobile .content h1 {
  color: #D6D6D4;
  font-size: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mobile .content p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 410px;
  color: #929584;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 18px
}

.mobile .content .sep {
  height: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C24147;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile .content .sep img {
  padding: 0 8px;
  background: #F9F9F9;
}

.mobile .content h2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #929584;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile .content .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.mobile .content .button {
  display: block;
  background: #010101;
  color: #F8F8F8;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile .content .button:hover {
  background: #222;
}

.mobile .content .button.apple img {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.mobile .content .button.apple span {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px; left: 42px;
}

.mobile .content .button.apple h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px; left: 42px;
  margin: 0;
}

.mobile .content .button.google img {
  margin: 18px 0 0 8px;
}

.mobile .content .button.google span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px; left: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mobile .content .button.google h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px; left: 38px;
  margin: 0;
}

.mobile .content .button.google h3 b {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Cardo', serif;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 4px
}

.contact {
  min-width: 1100px;
  background-image: url("img/fundo2es.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  color:white;
}

.contact .textocon {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 55px 75px 0 0;
}

.contact .textocon div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px
}

.contact .textocon h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.contact .textocon p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.contact .col1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 410px;
  padding: 10px 6px 10px 60px;
}

.contact .col1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.contact .col1 input {
  width: 380px;
  height: 20px;
}

.contact .col1 input,
.contact .col2 textarea {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgb(172, 161, 160);
  margin: 6px 0;
}
.contact .col1 input:focus,
.contact .col2 textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.contact .col2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 560px);
  padding: 52px 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.contact .col2 textarea {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 112px;
}

.contact .col2 #btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.contact .col2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.contact .info {
  padding: 10px 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact .info h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.contact .info p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.contact .info a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.contact .info a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}

.contact .info img {
  width: 32px;
  margin: 6px;
}
.contact .info img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fixedbar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title> Layout </title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="header" id="top">
      <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="current">Home</a>
        <a href="#tour">Product Tour</a>
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a href="#">Try</a>
        <a href="#vision">Vision</a>
      </div>
      <div class="move">
        <div class="center">
          <h1>Move work forward!</h1>
          <p>Optential keeps your team organized, connected, and focused on results.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mail1">
        <form action="form/form.php" method="post">
          <h1>Try Now!</h1>
          <input name="Email" class="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email address ...">
          <input type="submit" value="Get started for free">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mail2">
        <form action="form/form.php" method="post">
        <h1>Try Now!</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email here...">
        <input type="submit" id ="btn" value="Get started for free">
        <a class="top" href="#top">Top</a>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div id="slider">
        <div class="images">
          <div class="controls">
          <img src="img/3.png" alt="Image-1" />
          <img src="img/2.png" alt="Image-2" />
          <img src="img/1.png" alt="Image-3" />
          <img src="img/4.png" alt="Image-4" />
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="mobile">
      <div class="bar">
        <img src="img/barra2.png">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img class="mobimg" src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/mob.png">
        <div class="mob">
          <h1>Mobile</h1>
          <p>Optential combines the best of responsive software with native IOS and Android apps to provide the best experience and optimal results!</p>
          <p>On laptops, desktops, tablets and phones, always get the best experience on the most intuitive project management set of tools in the world!</p>
          <p class="sep">
            <img src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/a1.png">
          </p>
          <h2>Coming soon !</h2>
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
      <div class="textocon">
        <div>
          <h1>Optential</h1>
          <p>A new management system<br>for a new management paradigm!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form method="POST" id="contactos_form" action="form/contactengine.php" onsubmit="return submit_form(this);">
        <div class="col1">
          <h1>Contact us!</h1>
          <input type="text" name="Name" size="50" placeholder="Name"/>
          <input type="text" name="Email" size="50" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="text" name="Subject" size="50" placeholder="Subject"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <textarea name="Message" rows="5" cols="70" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
          <input type="submit" id="btn"value="Send"/>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="info">
        <div>
          <h1>Mail Us !</h1>
          <p>Rua Andrade Corvo, 242</p>
          <p>sala 206</p>
          <p>4700-204 Braga</p>
          <p>Portugal</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Call Us !</h1>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Email Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><p>code@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_hr@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_support@angel.com</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Join Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/gplus.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/instag.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script>
function submit_form(form){
  formulario=$("#contactos_form");

   $.ajax({url: formulario.attr("action"), method:formulario.attr("method"), data:formulario.serialize(), success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }});


  return false;
}


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The css of the slideshow is "slider" and "controls".

TL:DR: How can i make the controls of the slideshow be inside of it, close of the bottom and dont change position when we resize the window.

**EDIT**

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="controls">
      <img src="img/3.png" alt="Image-1" />
      <img src="img/2.png" alt="Image-2" />
      <img src="img/1.png" alt="Image-3" />
      <img src="img/4.png" alt="Image-4" />
    </div> 
    <div class="controls"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #slider {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#slider .images .controls  { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 658px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1s;
  left: 0;
}

#slider .images img {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.controls {
  width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 80%;
}

.controls div {

  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.controls .current {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename Controls class in #slider .images .controls. 
Move your circles parent -> (controls) to #slider .

Set this Css codes

```
.controls {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 80%;
}
#slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Edit this Code For #slider .image Set height to image's height.

```
height : Your Image's height;
```

And delete this Css code in Body

```
min-width:900px;
```

Comment: @BugaDroid: Oops , Code Edited .<br/> This code have a little problem in mobile . but your html codes !! this is not good idea one . you can set your images in #slider .image and set float left and height 300px for them ! and set #slider .image height to auto then your problems are fix

Comment: Now, slideshow is half the height and controls are still outside- http://i.imgur.com/m096IIk.jpg

Comment: @BugaDroid: Sorry what do you need ? you need controls come inside or out side ?

Comment: height of the images has to be 100% but if i do that the images disappear

Comment: ok, i just dont understand the first two lines, what i need to rename and move ?

Comment: sorry my English is terrible . you need change your css codes with my codes.and waite for me a moment i show you an image

Comment: your problem is it fix ?

Comment: If not, is better to you write all code on your awsner or here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I am gonna sleep, please provide me all code necessary if you can. Cya tomorrow !

Comment: Really kidding me ? you didn't edit your css codes !! access me to your host !